# How to forecast as a baker your next upcoming time slot by using baking rights RPC?

Tags: baking, rpc, baking-rights

1) "You get assigned slots to bake and endorse. If you are not online at the time of your slots, you miss them" -

->>Can a baker just stay **offline** UNTIL her next time slot comes up? I just want to know- can I be offline and then only come online to bake and then go offline again?

For this, I would need to estimate WHEN my next time slot will be. **How can I achieve this?**   And just to have a feeling, about what time dimensions are we speaking here, if I baked today-could it be that I bake again in a day, or more likely in 7 days, what are likely time horizons?

""It is going to be impossible to predict the exact time with high confidence. The baking rights RPC gives you some idea, but it is not accurate: you will see the timestamps moving forward as the rights get closer. ""

And What are these baking rights RPC? Where can I find their description and how to use them for my forecast of next time slots?

Thank you!!